# What does this Rails error expectation mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, redis, semaphore, resque

This failing test passes fine on my local, but on my remote testing server it fails. So I'm assuming this might be about a remote redis/resque configuration..

My error reads as so :

```
not all expectations were satisfied
  unsatisfied expectations:
  - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: Resque Client connected to redis://localhost:6379/0.enqueue(StoreArticulate::Bookmarks, 10, 'SecondBookmark000011101010101')
  satisfied expectations:
  - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: #<Mock:generic pusher channel>.trigger(any_parameters)
  - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: Pusher.[](any_parameters)
  - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: Panda::Video.find(any_parameters)
  - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: Resque Client connected to redis://localhost:6379/0.enqueue(any_parameters)
test: #bookmarks should update an existing bookmark. (QuizzesControllerTest)
test/functional/quizzes_controller_test.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <class:QuizzesControllerTest>'
```

The line of code, this refers to reads as follows :

```
should 'update an existing bookmark' do

  Resque.stubs(:enqueue)
  Resque.expects(:enqueue).with(StoreArticulate::Bookmarks, @quiz.id, @second_bookmark[0]).once

  post :state, registration: @quiz.id, method: 'POST', content: @first_bookmark
  post :state, registration: @quiz.id, method: 'POST', content: @second_bookmark
end
```

Could someone explain what exactly is going wrong here and what I might be able to do to remedy it?

Answer (score 1):

> - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: Resque Client connected to redis://localhost:6379/0.enqueue(StoreArticulate::Bookmarks, 10, 'SecondBookmark000011101010101')

I read that as your tests in your remote environment expect to have Resque actually be able to connect to Redis, running on localhost:6379.  I've gotten around this in the past by using something like [fakeredis](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/fakeredis) - it might be worth checking out, rather than trying to stub out Redis itself.